# Dreamweaver ERROR in TagEdit.setOuterHTML

Tags: text-editors, ide, dreamweaver

Every few seconds Dreamweaver pops up an error dialogue with:

> ERROR in TagEdit.setOuterHTML
>
> Cannot parse the following value for newOuterHTML:

Followed by a snippet from the current document.

The relevant section is this:

```
<?php 
foreach ($pictData['types'] as $type) { ?>
    <source media="(min-width: <?php echo $size; ?>px)"
            sizes=""
            srcset="<?php echo $pictData['names'][$type][$size]; ?>"
            type="<?php echo $type; ?>">
<?php   
} ?>
```

Which is part of a function to generate `<picture>` element sources. It's incomplete (so I don't know how well the code actually works, there could be an error that I'm not seeing), as it's very difficult to work on with Dreamweaver constantly complaining about... something. I'm guessing that something about the structure of the code is causing Dreamweaver to be unable to parse it. But I'm not sure why.

Other text editors aren't complaining, so at least  that's good. But I still would love to know why Dreamweaver is having this problem, and if there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem may be that you didn't escape the () by the media= part - also xou could have used ' instead of " that way the () would not have been interpreted as php structure but rather as text data.

i don't know why but for me it is a lot more readable to when i write it like this:

```
<?php 

    foreach ($type as $pictData['types']) {
        echo "<source media='(min-width: ".$size."px)'";
        echo "sizes=''";
        echo "srcset='".$pictData['names'][$type][$size]."'";
        echo "type='".$type."'>";
    }

?>
```

also you should keep a look at the foreach row i think it should be the other way round:

```
foreach ($pictData['types'] as $type) {
```

instead of ...

```
foreach ($type as $pictData['types']) {
```

Comment: Haha, you're right about the order being wrong. I figured I would have done something stupid. Unfortunately that doesn't fix it, but it will save me an error later. As to the other point, I prefer to avoid echoing HTML when it's not necessary. With syntax highlighting, it's much easier to read the other way (since the string isn't highlighted as HTML).